# Kitchen test and reboot Vagrant boxes

Tags: chef-infra, virtualbox, recipe, test-kitchen

I had wrote some cookbooks.
Now I want to test it using kitchen on multiple platforms.
I want to restart my virtualbox istance before install Visual Studio.
But when the machine reboots, my session is finished, and I'm not able to install Visual studio.
I use chef 12.5.1

It's possible install PowerShell 4, restart the virtual machine, and again restart my run chef and install visulstudio?
I state What if I do it from the customer cook everything works, but from kitchen is not working

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with Chef that old, you'll need to use 12.11 or later, but Test Kitchen supports this in general. An example of the relevant provisioner config:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero # or chef_solo
  require_chef_omnibus: 12.11 # need the RFC 062 exit codes
  retry_on_exit_code:
    - 35 # 35 is the exit code signaling that the node is rebooting
  max_retries: 1
  client_rb:
    exit_status: :enabled # Opt-in to the standardized exit codes
    client_fork: false  # Forked instances don't return the real exit code
```

Comment: Thanks you.
I try using chef 12.11.8 and this is the error:
Exception
Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
Failed to complete converge action.

What is the problem now?